# How to open a web link whenever user click on wxWidget event?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm creating an wxWidgets application and I'm trying to open a web link whenever user press an event.

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
    void OnViewHelp( wxCommandEvent &event );    
}
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE( MyFrame, wxFrame )
    EVT_MENU( wxID_ViewHelp, MyFrame :: OnViewHelp )
END_EVENT_TABLE()

    void OnViewHelp( wxCommandEvent &event )
    {
    //Open the www.google.com
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you searched for "browser" in the manual, you should have been able to find the [wxLaunchDefaultBrowser()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga3ff36fe489da2a779248b56f283615ca) function.

Answer (score 1):

bool wxLaunchDefaultBrowser(const wxString & url, int flags = 0 )